# Is it legal to write $A_\mu = (a, b, c, d)$?

Tags: notation

In special relativity (theoretical physics), one uses a lot of four-vectors. With regular vectors, I would say the following is okay:
$$
\vec A = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
A_1 = a
\qquad
A_2 = a
\qquad
A_3 = c
$$

It would be incorrect, however, to write something like:
$$
A_i = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}
$$

Since $A$ (or $\vec A$) is the vector, and $A_i$ is the $i$-th component of that vector.

In special relativity, I see the following all the time:
$$
A^\mu = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{pmatrix}
$$

Or the four-$\nabla$:
$$
\partial_\mu = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac 1c \frac{\partial}{\partial t}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
\partial_0 = \frac 1c \frac{\partial}{\partial t}
$$

So far, I have read in “Mathematical methods for Physicists” (Arfken & Weber) that everything is okay, as long as one does not write $\vec A = A^\mu$ or $A = A^\mu$. Some Physicists don't even understand the problem, others say that this $\partial_\mu = (\ldots)$ is wrong, but they are Physicists and ignore that.

Is writing $\partial_\mu = (\ldots)$ okay or just sloppy notation that virtually everybody uses? If it is okay, what about the ambiguity of $\partial_\mu$ and $\partial_0$?

Comment: In most states...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a, b, and c are real numbers the first equality is wrong, because LHS is a scalar (the i-th component of the vector, i.e., a, b, or c), while the RHS is a vector.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in special relativity, but I guess the meaning of the notation
$$ A^\mu = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{pmatrix} $$
is that $\mu = (0,1,2,3)$ is a [multi-index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_notation) which picks the entries $0,1,2$ and $3$ of $A$.